# Dell R610 idrac upgrade

Tags: dell, drac, firmware

Recently I found out that iDrac has security issues [here](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2013-4783/) and according dell is not supposed to be connected to internet.

I'm trying to upgrade it's firmware so I downloaded bootable iso from https://dell.app.box.com/v/BootableR610/folder/32719590128.

I checked the md5 which is correct. I used dd command to put the iso to the usb disk but it would not boot. I tried BIOS and UEFI. Now I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Why not just follow the directions Dell provides for upgrading?  The point in the security issue is these shouldn't be connected to the public internet (it shouldn't be reachable by someone not on YOUR network).  It's perfectly fine to have it on your local network and upgrade it like it says in the manual.  If you can plug a USB disk in you can plug a network cable in directly and install it that way and not be connected to the internet.

Comment: First, dell suggest to run exe file on windows installed on the server, which I don't have. Second is not possible if the server is hosted in server farm. Third, booting the image is direction from Dell

Comment: Booting an ISO from a flash disk isn't necessarily going to work.  Burn it to DVD and install from there if you have to use this method.  Instead, I'd recommend you use the built-in "lifecycle controller" to do the firmware updates.  It's a boot option like BIOS, choose it via one of the f-keys at boot time.  You'll have to configure the lifecycle controller's network but from there the firmware update process is pretty easy - just say "FTP" and don't fill in anything else, it will automatically grab it from dell's ftp site.